# Blocking Malicious Requests PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have been receiving requests from ip addresses which seems to me like attempts to gain control over the system. These seem to be **DOS** Attacks due to the sleep(x) function attached. But not all of them have the sleep function, so I need to know which kind of attack are these. I'm attaching the screenshot's of the apache logs that I had taken.

[image]

[image]

For the time being I have blocked the IP and set the time out limit to 2 seconds.
But I am still not satisfied and would like to know if there's any other preventive measures that I can take.

Comment: sql attack..  SQL Injection Attack

Comment: From [Related: How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1). But since you have these codes on your database, it seems that you already have some sort of 'fix' (I can be wrong). Anyways, this doesn't seem like a DOS attack at all.

Comment: Nah, (D)DOS attack ([Denial Of Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack)) tries to tackle your system by overloading it. This is just an attempt to retrieve data from your database, which _could_ succeed if you aren't protected against sql injection (see @FirstOne's link).

Comment: Somebody is scanning your server for vulnerabilities. This is why [handling input securely](http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Input-Validation.html) is so important.

Comment: @FirstOne Thank's For the link. It really helped me. I guess I wasn't searching for the right thing.

Comment: Glad to help. @ProgrammerBaba